# Spring injection - custom annotation to initialise classes

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, jbehave

Currently I need to create beans for all the classes (which hold the step definitions in my selenium/jbehave framework). If I don't do this the test step will report as pending (so basically the steps classes needs to be initialised).

bean.xml:

```
    <bean id="one" class="com.test.automation.steps.OneSteps">
    </bean>

    <bean id="two" class="com.test.automation.steps.TwoSteps">
    </bean>

    <bean id="three" class="com.test.automation.steps.ThreeSteps">
    </bean>

    <bean id="four" class="com.test.automation.steps.FourSteps">
    </bean>
```

I think there should be an easier way of doing this, instead of creating beans for every class, I should be able to create a custom annotation and then just tag each class.

Is this a possibility and an example would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: You mean like using the `@Component` annotation?

Comment: I believe so, but not sure how to implement this. It sounds fairly simple, I just want to initialise all classes under the steps package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeanFactory to create instances

From docs

The BeanFactory is the actual container which instantiates, configures, and manages a number of beans. These beans typically collaborate with one another, and thus have dependencies between themselves. These dependencies are reflected in the configuration data used by the BeanFactory (although some dependencies may not be visible as configuration data, but rather be a function of programmatic interactions between beans at runtime).

A BeanFactory is represented by the interface org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory, for which there are multiple implementations. The most commonly used simple BeanFactory implementation is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory. (This should be qualified with the reminder that ApplicationContexts are a subclass of BeanFactory, and most users end up using XML variants of ApplicationContext).

Read more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html) and [here](http://www.pretechsol.com/2013/06/spring-beanfactory-example.html)